# Job/Task in Kubernetes and Spring Cloud Task

Tags: kubernetes, spring-cloud-task

I created a Pod that have `@EnableTaskLauncher` with `spring-cloud-deployer-kubernetes`. It is receiving task requests through `spring-cloud-stream` and launching the tasks.

Everything is working perfectly except that I want the task to be launched as `Kind: Job` instead of `Kind: Deployment` .

I could not find any configuration or property in `spring-cloud-deployer-kubernetes` that do this or if it is available .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We moved away from the Jobs to Bare-pods model for Spring Cloud Task (in SCDF) to better control its lifecycle such as the clean shutdown of the container when the SCT-operation is complete.

However, there's [spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer-kubernetes#163](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer-kubernetes/pull/163) that adds an option to choose between Jobs vs. Pods for Tasks. Please try it out and give us feedback on the PR.

Comment: Also, I'm interested in learning how are you using SCSt, SCT and the K8S-Deployer without SCDF. Any insights into this would be useful.

Comment: Thanks , I will give it a try. I created a sample project to show how I am running SCSt and SCT https://github.com/shahbour/task-k8s. I will update it with the above PR

Comment: I just did try the branch above and it worked perfectly I got the jobs. Now I am trying to figure out who should be responsible for queueing the jobs in case no resources are available, task launcher or Kubernetes